# gcc __attribute__ section not working?

Tags: c, memory, xilinx, zynq, linker

I'm working on a Zynq Ultrascale+ MPSoC and trying to play around with the on and off chip memories. In the following program, I'm trying to place only variable 'x' into OCM (on-chip-memory) where everything else is loaded into external DDR.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "platform.h"
#include "xil_printf.h"

volatile u32 x __attribute__ ((section ("psu_ocm_ram_0_MEM_0"))) = 10;
volatile u32 *p = &x;

int main()
{
    init_platform();

    xil_printf("x = %u\r\n", x);
    xil_printf("p = %p\r\n", p);

    cleanup_platform();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
x = 10
p = 2AB0
```

So it doesn't look like p is pointing to a variable in OCM memory according to the memory map below.

[image]

If I change to linker script to put the entire .data section into OCM (and get rid of the gcc attribute), then the output becomes as I expected:

```
x = 10
p = FFFC0130
```

The weird thing is that the .map file for the original program does show that the linker is trying to do *something* with the variable, I'm just not sure what:

```
                0x0000000000002ab0                __data_end = .

.tm_clone_table
                0x0000000000002ab0        0x0
 .tm_clone_table
                0x0000000000002ab0        0x0 
 .tm_clone_table
                0x0000000000002ab0        0x0 

.igot.plt       0x0000000000002ab0        0x0
 .igot.plt      0x0000000000002ab0        0x0 

psu_ocm_ram_0_MEM_0
                0x0000000000002ab0        0x4
 psu_ocm_ram_0_MEM_0
                0x0000000000002ab0        0x4 ./src/helloworld.o
                0x0000000000002ab0                x
```

So it looks like the variable is being placed at the end of the .data section, which is in DDR (for the original code), but I want the variable in OCM. Anybody know what's going on here?

Comment: Much as I hate plowing through lots of lines of code -- post your linker script (whatever.ld), or at least the part that defines memory sections.  It looks like the **\_\_attribute\_\_** part is working, but the **linker** is putting the segment in the wrong spot.

Comment: Your comment got me thinking I wasn't doing something properly with the linker script. Turns out I was trying to put the variable directly into OCM memory with the gcc variable attribute. I needed to create a custom section in the linker script, tell the linker that this section ought to live in OCM, then reference that section in the gcc variable attribute. All good now, thanks!

Comment: If you can, take the time to answer your question yourself with a before & after snippet from the linker script (or maybe just "I added these lines in the ... section").  If you're asking, there's at least 100 other people out there wondering.

Comment: One of the 100, here....

Comment: This looks like a screen shot from Crossworks? If so, there are ways to do this through an XML file rather than manually writing the linker script, though either way should work.

Comment: This is from Xilinx SDK. I didn't manually write the linker script. I just modified it slightly to tell it where in memory to put a specific variable.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out I wasn't using the gcc attribute correctly. I was trying to place the variable directly into OCM using:

```
volatile u32 x __attribute__ ((section ("psu_ocm_ram_0_MEM_0"))) = 10;
```

as if the compiler is able to put individual variables into specific memory locations. Rather, it's the linker that's responsible for assigning all executable code (data and instructions) to physical memory. It order to make this work, I had to create a custom section in the linker script and assign this section to OCM:

```
.my_section : {
    KEEP(*(.my_section))
} > psu_ocm_ram_0_MEM_0
```

Then in my code:

```
volatile u32 x __attribute__ ((section (".my_section"))) = 10;
```

The output was then:

```
x = 10
p = FFFC0000
```

as expected.